# sed: find blank/empty line after block then add line

Tags: sed

I was using:

```
sed '/\Additional categories/a new'
```

and it works great for inserting a new line immediately after the pattern.

Now I need to find a block, then get to the first blank line, and insert another blank line. File example:

```
    Additional categories
      stuff A
      stuff B

      other stuff
      other stuff

    Additional categories
      stuff A
      stuff B
      stuff C
      stuff D

      other stuff
      other stuff
```

Desired result:

```
    Additional categories
      stuff A
      stuff B


      other stuff
      other stuff

    Additional categories
      stuff A
      stuff B
      stuff C
      stuff D


      other stuff
      other stuff
```

Just a blank line is added, so that I have more space to make changes in the data file. If you can find this already, share the link and I will delete my question. Thanks.

Comment: Please add expected output in code tags too in your post and let me know then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this gnu sed

```
sed '/Additional categories/{:A;N;/\n$/!bA;s/$/\n/}' infile
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!

Comment: If I wanted to add 3 spaces on the first blank line after the block, would that work okay? Or would I have to use a second command?

Comment: The part to add line is s/$/\n/. \n is one line. If you want 2 --> \n\n.